# multi method for api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash does not seem to exist

Tags: query

Could you tell me what is wrong with this code?
Is there a way to achieve multiple query?

<index.mjs>

```
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://localhost:9944'); //running archive node
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const heightToTimestamp = async (height1, height2, height3) => {
    await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash.multi([
        height1, height2, height3
    ], (results) => { console.log(results) });
}

heightToTimestamp(10000000, 9999999, 9999998);
```

Answer (score 5):

`.multi` is only available on [storage queries](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.multi), i.e. via `api.query.*` endpoints.

There are RPCs available to query over multiple storage keys at once (for both subscriptions and one-shot results), when `.multi` is used the API uses these RPCs under the hood, instead of the single-key versions.

RPCs themselves, i.e. those on `api.rpc.*` are only available in the form the node exposes them.

For you use-case, you would use the following form, making the RPC queries in parallel using the available RPC -

```js
const results = await Promise.all([
  api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(height1),
  api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(height2),
  api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(height3)
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I got it.